# How to group rows in a Numpy 2D matrix based on column values?

Tags: python, numpy

What  would be an efficient (time, easy) way of grouping a `2D` `NumPy` matrix rows by different column conditions (e.g. group by column 2 values) and running `f1()` and `f2()` on each of those groups?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(my_numpy_array,key=itemgetter(1))
```

or maybe something like

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
print groupby(my_numpy_array,key = itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: This answer suggests general Python functions, thus the performance is likely to be significantly lower than in numpy.

Answer (score 10):

If you have an array `arr` of shape `(rows, cols)`, you can get the vector of all values in column 2 as

```
col = arr[:, 2]
```

You can then construct a boolean array with your grouping condition, say group 1 is made up of those rows with have a value larger than 5 in column 2:

```
idx = col > 5
```

You can apply this boolean array directly to your original array to select rows:

```
group_1 = arr[idx]
group_2 = arr[~idx]
```

For example:

```
>>> arr = np.random.randint(10, size=(6,4))
>>> arr
array([[0, 8, 7, 4],
       [5, 2, 6, 9],
       [9, 5, 7, 5],
       [6, 9, 1, 5],
       [8, 0, 5, 8],
       [8, 2, 0, 6]])
>>> idx = arr[:, 2] > 5
>>> arr[idx]
array([[0, 8, 7, 4],
       [5, 2, 6, 9],
       [9, 5, 7, 5]])
>>> arr[~idx]
array([[6, 9, 1, 5],
       [8, 0, 5, 8],
       [8, 2, 0, 6]])
```

Answer (score 6):

A compact solution is to use [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) (disclaimer: I am its author), which implements a fully vectorized solution to this type of problem:

The simplest way to use it is as:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
npi.group_by(arr[:, col1]).mean(arr)
```

But this also works:

```
# run function f1 on each group, formed by keys which are the rows of arr[:, [col1, col2]
npi.group_by(arr[:, [col1, col2]], arr, f1)
```

Comment: Hi Eelco! Unfortunately I couldn't reach you on some other way. Looks like we work on quite similar projects. Please have a look at https://github.com/ml31415/numpy-groupies , it's also a set of groupby operations for numpy. Instead of having two similar projects around, it may make sense to join forces.